# Approch for use rtk query hook for sending request when ever params are exist not always?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, knex.js

I use rtk query and mutations in my app and I use hooks in my components that I pass some params to them by props or context. I want to they send request when ever props is exist not always send request to backend

```
const packageDetail = useGetPackageDetailQuery({ id })
```

When id exists, just send it. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `skipToken` or the `skip` option:

```js
const packageDetail = useGetPackageDetailQuery(id ? { id } : skipToken)
```

or

```js
const packageDetail = useGetPackageDetailQuery({ id }, { skip: !id })
```